# How to handle store with ConnectedRouter + Redux

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to Reactjs. I'm making samples.

I'm using ConnectedRouter to move pages.
It seems not to get status in Page01 component.

```
const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history} >
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
                <Route exact path="/page1" component={Page01}/>
                <Route exact path="/page2" component={Page02}/>
            </Switch>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Page01 extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       this.fetchData('https://594ecc215fbb1a00117871a4.mockapi.io/comments');
    }

    fetchData(url){
        this.setState({isLoading: true});
        fetch(url).then((response) => {
            if(!response.ok){
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            this.setState({isLoading: false});
            return response;
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((comments) => this.setState({ comments }))
            .catch(() => this.setState({ hasError: true }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.comments.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                        {item.comment}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default connect((state) => state)(Page01);
```

I would like to get json data and show them in render.
`this.state.comments` is always undefined.

What do you think?

Comment: Where you have defined `comments` state

Comment: I defined it in reducer in configreStore.

Comment: Happy to help start a conversation here. Is there an issue with binding "this"??? Perhaps an arrow function for "fetchData" might help get started. Replace "fetchData(url){" with "fetchData = url => {"

Comment: give me 3 hours to get back. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I replaced "fetchData(url){" to "fetchData = url => {" . It does not work.

Comment: Sorry. When I tried original script again. It worked. I don't know why. Provably I had a cache or something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Added initialize state in constructor.

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            comments: [],
            isLoading: false,
            hasError: false
        }
    }
```

It works.